# Comparing values in the same object

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to write some code to check if two people share the same birthday. As you can see person "a" and person "b" do not share the same birthday, but the output on the console is:

```
a was born on day 1
a has the same birthday as a
a has the same birthday as b
b was born on day 2
b has the same birthday as a
b has the same birthday as b
```

while it should be:

```
a was born on day 1
a has the same birthday as a
b was born on day 2
b has the same birthday as b
```

---

Code:

```
var people = {
    a: {
        name: "a",
        birthday: 1,
    },
    b: {
        name: "b",
        birthday: 2,
    }
};


for(var x in people) {
    console.log(people[x].name + " was born on day " + people[x].birthday)
    for(var y in people) {
        if(people[x].birthday = people[y].birthday) {
            console.log(people[x].name + " has the same birthday as " + people[y].name)
        }
    }
}
```

---

```
people[x].birthday = people[y].birthday
```

seems to be the source of the problem.

Comment: You can use people[x].birthday === people[y].birthday

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
people[x].birthday == people[y].birthday
```

you need `==` instead of `=`. `=` is assignment, `==` is comparison

by using `=`, you are assigning `people[y].birthday` value to `people[x].birthday` value, and then the two birthdays are the same.

by using `==`, you will be comparing if `y` is the same birthday as `x`

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use the Identity / strict equality operator `===` to compare two objects in JavaScript, so you can do :

```
people[x].birthday === people[y].birthday
```

Take a look at **[Comparison operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)**.

**Note:**

`people[x].birthday = people[y].birthday` will always be `true` because here you are doing an assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You can use === . this means : equal value and equal type

See more at : http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Two problems here:

1. Your comparison looks like assignment and not equality check

`people[x].birthday = people[y].birthday`

Should be:

```
people[x].birthday === people[y].birthday
```

2. The second is that in  your for loops. You loop through the collection twice starting at the same index (0).

The easiest way would be just to compare the current person with each of the people in the list be

```
for(var index = 0; index < people.length; index++) {
   console.log(people[x].name + " was born on day " + people[x].birthday)
    for(var inner = index; inner < people.length; inner+1) {
        if(people[index].birthday == people[inner].birthday) {
            console.log(people[index].name + " has the same birthday as " + people[inner].name)
        }
    }
}
```